# Cassandra time window compaction vs Bucket key for time series data

Tags: cassandra

As I understand cassandra prefers each parition to have 100K rows and data size to be between 10MB to 100 MB

Now when we are using time window compaction strategy it will break partition into buckets.
- are there buckets based on insertion time or time in some timestamp column ( ideally i have timestamp column which is cluster key)

Along with timestamp compaction do I still need bucket key ? like month of year and so on..

Yes this is for iot application so data will keep coming into partition for long long time

I see from other post that bucket key is still needed

- Also using time compaction does it allow me more lenient in terms of partitions size

Comment: It is all depend on the use case how you will be using it while retrieving.

Comment: How does retrieving imact here.. I will be retriving by device and time

Comment: we are using lstm tree how you want tree to designed ..